# Android thread just stops

Tags: java, android, udp, wifi, adb

I've got a thread that deals with receiving and sending out UDP packets, this works fine until X amount of packets have been received, and then the client just stops trying to receive packets, and stops sending them, all of the catch functions don't display anything, the client just stops asking for packets.
Here is my client run code

```
public void run()
{
    if( host == true ) { setUpClient(); server.start(); }
    rdyForPlay = true;
    boolean run = true;
    boolean setupPlayer = false;
    while( run )
    {
        //Tell the server to give position of players
        //if( setupPlayer == true )
        //{
        //  setUpClient();
        //  setupPlayer = false;
        //}

        if( host == false )
        {
            try {
                if(socket == null)
                {
                    socket = new DatagramSocket( port );
                }
                byte[] bufer = new byte[256];
                //String msg = "position";
                String msg = ID +":"+ assets[ID].returnPosX() +":"+ assets[ID].returnPosY();
                int msgLength = msg.length();
                bufer = msg.getBytes();
                InetAddress address;
                address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.59");
                DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket( bufer, bufer.length , address, port );
                socket.send( p );

            } catch (UnknownHostException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d(TAG, "Error with unknown host");
                e2.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d(TAG, "Error with socket");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d(TAG, "Error with sending/receiving data");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            byte[] buf = new byte[256];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length );
            try 
            {
                socket.receive( packet );
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error with receiving data");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String data = new String( buf, 0, packet.getLength() );
            //Split the string up
            String[] dataArray = data.split("#");
            int newTotalPlayers = Integer.parseInt( dataArray[0] );
            if( newTotalPlayers != totalPlayers )
            {
                Log.d(TAG," what is total amount of players:" + newTotalPlayers);
                if( newTotalPlayers == 1 )
                {
                    newPlayer( 0 );
                    totalPlayers = newTotalPlayers;
                }
                else
                {
                    newPlayer( newTotalPlayers );
                    totalPlayers = newTotalPlayers;
                }
                //if( ID == 0 && host == false)
                //{
                //  ID = newTotalPlayers;
                //  setupPlayer = true;
                //}
            }
            //Do a for loop to go through dataArray
            for( int i = 0; i < totalPlayers; i++)
            {
                String[] pos = dataArray[(i + 1)].split(":");
                if( Integer.parseInt( pos[(i*3)] ) == ID )
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Do nothing please");
                }
                else
                {
                    assets[i].setPosition( Integer.parseInt( pos[(i*3) + 1] ), Integer.parseInt( pos[(i*3) + 2] ) );
                }
            }

        }

    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Error with run value");
}
```

This works fine, It just really bugs me that the connection is dropped after so long for some strange reason, which I can't find as nothing is printed at all to LogCat

Canvas

P.S. more code can be given if needed

Here is my server run method

```
public void run() {
    InetAddress client = null;
    boolean run = true;
    String data = "";
    DatagramPacket packet = null;
    while( run )
    {
        if( data.equalsIgnoreCase( "" ) )
        {
            /*Log.d(TAG, "waiting for clients");
            String msg = "waiting";
            int msgLength = msg.length();
            byte[] message = msg.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket( message, msgLength, client, port );
            try 
            {
                socket.send( p );
            } 
            catch (IOException e2) 
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error with sending");
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }*/
        }

        //Send some data
        if( data.equalsIgnoreCase( "connect" ) )
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "ID send :" + packet.getAddress());
            address.add( packet.getAddress() );
            players += 1;
            String msg = String.valueOf( players );
            int msgLength = msg.length();
            byte[] message = msg.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket( message, msgLength, packet.getAddress(), port );
            try 
            {
                socket.send( p );
            } 
            catch (IOException e2) 
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error with sending");
                e2.printStackTrace();
                data = "";
            }
        }

        //if( /*data.equalsIgnoreCase( "position" )*/ address.size() > 0 )
        //{
            //Create for loop to create the string
            String msg = "";
            msg = players + "#";
            for(int i = 0; i < players; i++)
            {
                        msg += + i + ":" + assets.get(i).returnPosX() + ":" + assets.get(i).returnPosY() + ":"; 
            }
            //msg = String.valueOf( 
            //      players + ":" + 
            //      "1:" + assets.get(0).returnPosX() + ":" + assets.get(0).returnPosY() );
            int msgLength = msg.length();
            byte[] message = msg.getBytes();
            for(int i = 0; i < address.size() ; i++)
            {
                DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket( message, msgLength, address.get(i), port );
                try 
                {
                    socket.send( p );
                } 
                catch (IOException e2) 
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error with sending");
                    e2.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
            //Log.d(TAG, "Data sent is:" + msg);
        //}

        data = " ";

        //Receive some data
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
        packet = new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length );
        try 
        {
            socket.receive( packet );
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error with receiving data");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        data = new String( buf, 0, packet.getLength() );
        //Log.d(TAG, "Data received was :" + data);

        try 
        {
            this.sleep( 25 );
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d(TAG, "Error with trying to sleep");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Error with while run value");
}
```

Sorry about the comments

Comment: interesting, may be the connection is auto-stopped somehow?

Comment: I will post my server run method

Comment: I would add logging showing when client 1) is going to receive a packet (including the number of received packets); 2) has received a packet (including the number of received packets); 3) terminates. In general, I have seen WiFi disconnecting and reconnecting for no apparent reason; you probably need to reconnect if this is the case.

Comment: How long (in time) before this occur? Could it be that the device enters sleep mode?

Comment: nope, I keep playing with both devices so they never even dim :), 1844... :p what would be a good way for me to reconnect? could I create a boolean variable, that is only true, once it has received something, and if that boolean variable is true, it won't try and receive anything until it at least sends something? would this maybe stop the deadlock? if not any chance you could give some simple example code?

Comment: You should also look at the traces of both client and server and to see if there are any deadlocks... on either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a Deadlock scenario is taking place with both Source codes hanging on `socket.receive`

Fortunately the code for Android and J2SE UDP Server Client codes are identical so try this code in your machine and debug to see what's happening. You can put print statements to know better.

Furthermore UDP is unreliable. I don't see a packet receiving acknowledgement and resending mechanism implemented in your code. This is required. You can't just assume that the Packet you send will be received to the other end.

Comment: Could you provide some example code? also read my comment to 1844 above

Comment: With a simple boolean variable added, there is no more deadlock :)